# How to create a dump of oracle schema with tables matching certain pattern only

Tags: database, oracle, server-administration

I want to transfer the AB% and AC% tables of a schema from one server to another server in oracle.

How do i create a dump with only the tables that start with AB and AC in their name.

I have tried this command but it dumps all the tables in the schema to the dmp file.

```
expdp SYSTEM/password SCHEMAS=hr DIRECTORY=dmpdir DUMPFILE=schema.dmp LOGFILE=expschema.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the INCLUDE option:

```
expdp SYSTEM/password SCHEMAS=hr DIRECTORY=dmpdir DUMPFILE=schema.dmp LOGFILE=expschema.log INCLUDE=TABLE:"LIKE 'AB%'",TABLE:"LIKE 'AC%'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since my operating system is windows, I have to use the following command.

```
expdp SYSTEM/password SCHEMAS=hr DIRECTORY=dmpdir DUMPFILE=schema.dmp LOGFILE=expschema.log INCLUDE=TABLE:"LIKE 'AB%'",TABLE:\"LIKE \'AC%\'\"
```